# Remove one view from set of views

Tags: ios, objective-c

there is an array of views declared as

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *views;
```

Each view is a subview of previous one (like a deck of cards) . Something like this:

```
     ____________
    | A   ______|_____ 
    |    | B_________|___ 
    |    |  | C .    .   |
    |____|..|……….    .   | 
         |__|………………………   |
            |____________|
```

And I need to remove one view (e.g. view B here) and make its subview (view C here) take view's B place. That's what I do during animation:

```
CGPoint oldCenter = [view center]; // view must be removed
MyView *subView = [MyView new];

subView = [[view subviews] firstObject]; // there is only one view’s subview 

MyView *superView = (MyView *)[view superview];

[view removeFromSuperview];

[superView addSubview:subView];

[subView setCenter:subView.superview.center];
[subView setCenter:oldCenter];
```

And not only `view` is being removed, but also its subview and I get only `A` and really don't know what to do.

Comment: Instead of adding next view in previous view and making a chain, add them all to a parent view and manage accordingly.

Comment: @AdilSoomro  Thanks for advice, but I need exactly chain of views

Comment: Could you paste a little more code? As far as I understood, you have the view A as "superview", view B as "view", and view C as "subview", right?

Comment: @Walucas correct. And I want to get rid of B and make C subview of A

Comment: Try to use subView = [[[view subviews] firstObject] retain]; and let me know if that works

Comment: @Walucas thanks for your reply. I solved the problem and that was my fault. I forgot to update constraints

Answer (score 0):

When ever you remove a view, you remove all the objects thats on it. It's like taking a page out a book, the text on that page is also being removed. Now what you've done is that you made C a subview of B right? Now if we keep with the theory of a book, you placed a post-it note on that page. Now when we now remove that page (B) which has text (Objects) and a post-it note(C), everything gets taken out and all what is left is the other pages (A). Rather than making them a subview of the previous one, make them all a subviews of A (only if A isn't getting taken out ever). Hope this helped!!

Answer (score 0):

If A as "superview", view B as "view", and view C as "subview" - then before removing 'view'-B add it's 'subview'-c to 'superview'-A.

```
CGPoint oldCenter = [view center]; // view must be removed
MyView *subView = [MyView new];

subView = [[view subviews] firstObject]; // there is only one view’s subview

MyView *superView = (MyView *)[view superview];

[superView addSubview:subView];
[view removeFromSuperview];

[subView setCenter:subView.superview.center];
[subView setCenter:oldCenter];
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. By removing view I removed it constraints so I had to set them again. And that was the problem

Comment: Great. I was expecting to mark my answer true or up vote if somehow it helps you. Thanks.